# mod_rewrite keep rewriting recursilvely

Tags: linux, apache, mod-rewrite, web

I just want to append the `url` with `home` but it is happening in recursion and i get the browser saying too many redirects

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   #RewriteRule ^test main.html
   RewriteRule rest/(.*)$ /home/rest/$1 [R=301]
</IfModule>
```

so i want

```
localhost/rest/abc.php
```

to

```
localhost/home/rest/abc.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the slash before home.

```
 RewriteRule ^rest/(.*)$ home/rest/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: I tried that then it get redirect loop `Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.` because `rest` again gets redirect and again

Comment: I added ^ in front of the rest, can you try it.